# Spring JMS - getting SecurityContext from Message Driven Pojo (MDP)

Tags: spring-security, spring-jms

The 'standard' way (AFAIK) to get a Spring Security Context to, say, determine the current logged in user is:

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

However if I run this same code in a JMS Message Driven Pojo (MDP), the context is null.

This make sense because a JMS event doesn't necessarily happen within a session, which is where the security context would live.

But since that's the case, is there a (standard) way for the security to be propagated through to the MDP, or, a way for it to be injected into the MDP?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't.  Anything you need from the session / security has to be put on to the message itself, probably in the headers.